# How to match a string that contains a Python unordered set object when testing across multiple systems and Python versions?

Tags: python-3.x, regex, set, pytest

I have a CI setup that is running tests across Python versions >= 3.7 and on Ubuntu and macOS systems. I have a test that seems to randomly fail and I'm wondering if it has to do with how unordered sets are stored in memory on different systems. The error is a failure where a warning is raised correctly but it does not match the expected warning message because it is showing the regex pattern printed with a different order of the set object. I wonder if there is a better way to compare unordered sets when they are inserted as an object into an f-string regex.

For clarity I have the following function I am testing:

```py
def check_items(item):
    my_set = {True, False, "item1", "item2", "item3"}
    if item not in my_set:
        raise ValueError(
            f"Parameter reorder needs to be one of {my_set}."
        )
    return item
```

And in a separate test file I have the following test

```py
import pytest

my_set = {True, False, "item1", "item2", "item3"}

def test_check_items_error():
    with pytest.raises(
            ValueError,
            match=f"Parameter reorder needs to be one of {my_set}"
    ):
        check_items("new")
```

The failure of the test is

```bash
AssertionError: Regex pattern did not match.
 Regex: "Parameter reorder needs to be one of {False, True, 'item1', 'item2', 'item3'}"
 Input: "Parameter reorder needs to be one of {False, True, 'item2', 'item1', 'item3'}."
```

What is the safest way to make sure that identical unordered sets are matched correctly in this setting where they are inserted into an f-strings?

Comment: You shouldn't try to compare sets as strings. Parse the string back into a set, then compare that. You can use `ast.literal_eval()` to parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can "normalize" the set by sorting the repr of each set element. That way, the result will be in order:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pytest


def check_items(item):
    my_set = {True, False, "item1", "item2", "item3"}
    if item not in my_set:
        normalized = ", ".join(sorted(repr(e) for e in my_set))
        raise ValueError(f"Parameter reorder needs to be one of {normalized}.")
    return item




def test_check_items_error():
    my_set = {"item1", "item2", "item3", False, True}
    normalized = ", ".join(sorted(repr(e) for e in my_set))
    with pytest.raises(
        ValueError, match=f"Parameter reorder needs to be one of {normalized}"
    ):
        check_items("new")
```

In this case, no matter how your order your set, the message will come out to be

```
Parameter reorder needs to be one of 'item1', 'item2', 'item3', False, True.
```